# CABasicAnimation Property Listings

Tags: swift, core-animation, apple-documentation

I'm following a Core Animation tutorial and the narrator created a CABasicAnimation object and began using all these different properties of the object such as duration, repeatCount, and autoReverse.  The problem I'm experiencing is that when I research Apple's [CABasicAnimation documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cabasicanimation#overview), it doesn't show these properties.  I think its really cool that the narrator found these properties to make use of them and I'd like to know how do I improve my research skills or where am I not looking in Apple's documentation to find these properties that the narrator uses?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what properties you are referring to, but if you follow the [documentation for `CABasicAnimation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cabasicanimation#overview) (that you linked to) you can see that it inherits from [`CAPropertyAnimation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/capropertyanimation) which in turn inherits from [`CAAnimation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/caanimation), both of which define and document some additional properties.

Additionally, you can see that it conforms to [`CAMediaTiming`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/camediatiming), which cover the timing related properties of all animations.

Together, these should provide the documentation for all the public properties that you can configure and rely upon.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Core Animation programming guide:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Specifically the section on animating layer content.

Hope that helps.